# Is there a way to style an MUI React component using it's own sx property, for hover on parent component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to style an MUI React component using it's own sx property, for hover on parent component?
For example, I have a Box child component within a Fab parent component. I want to use the sx prop of Box such that if the Fab is hovered over, the Box styling is changed. I don't want to change the sx prop of Fab for this purpose.

Comment: Using css you can't target the parent from a child element. A new css selector ":has()" gives you this ability but is working only in latest Safari at the moment. So you can't use the 'sx' property to achieve that. If you' re interested in a different approach you can have at the '<Box>' element  a function that is called on 'onMouseOver', and changes the style of the parent.

Comment: A related question: is it possible to define a rule in global scope in the sx property of a component? If yes, then can that be used in some way to achieve the kind of rule we are discussing?

Comment: If I understand correct what you mean, then it would be a similar approach as my initial answer in the sandbox I posted before (let me know if you want me to undelete my previous answer so you can see it). But to have an 'onMouseOver' function in your children which it finds the parent element and changes the style should make you achieve what you initially asked. In case I haven't understand, please, either create a sandbox so we can work on it, or edit the one I sent you. Thanks

Comment: How will it be similar approach to the initial answer? In the initial answer, there was a css rule in the sx prop of the parent component, that is for the styling of child component on hover on parent. In the new approach (that I am wondering whether it is supported), there needs to be a css rule in the sx prop of the child component, that is somehow *application-global* in scope (don't know whether it is supported?) but by using css classes defined on both parent and child components, is able to target the needed child component(s).